# Why does the order of template parameters matter to the MS C++ compiler in this example?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11

The following code compiles fine in GCC but in Visual Studio it results in

> error C2782: '`bool contains(const T &,const std::initializer_list<T2>`
>   `&)`' : template parameter '`T`' is ambiguous see declaration of
>   '`contains`' could be '`const wchar_t *`' or       '`std::wstring`'

It does however compile and work if the order of the template parameters is given as

`template<typename T2, typename T>`

Is this a compiler bug?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, typename T2>
bool contains(T const& value, std::initializer_list<T2> const& set)
{
  return std::find(std::begin(set), std::end(set), value) != std::end(set);
}

int main(void)
{
  std::set<std::wstring> values = { L"bar", L"not" };

  for (std::wstring val : values) {
    std::wcout << "\"" << val << "\" ";
    if (contains(val, { L"foo", L"bar", L"baz", L"doom" })) {
      std::wcout << "found" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
      std::wcout << "not found" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: I have created a bugreport: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/982338/template-parameter-order-matters

Comment: Yikes, I'm staying out of this one...

Comment: Makes no freaking sense... i.e. it's a bug :)

Comment: FWIW this _will_ compile if you explicitly specify the second argument passed as `std::initializer_list<std::wstring>{ ... }`.

Comment: changing the order of the template parameters here is equivalent to changing the order of the function's formal arguments, plus the order of actual arguments in calls. it should not mattter. hence it's a bug. you can report it at (https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Are you sure? Since T and T2 are used differently I find that counter-intuitive but I may not know the definition of "formal arguments" you are using.

Comment: @Sarien: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/099ca9b067fd198b

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf When you say formal arguments are you referring to formal template arguments? I don't understand what you are trying to tell me with the example.

Comment: @Sarien: C++11 §8.3.5/11 "An identifier can optionally be provided as a parameter name; if present in a function definition (8.4), it
names a parameter (sometimes called “formal argument”)"

Comment: Yeah, obvious bug. There's no way in hell `T` could possibly be deduced to be `const wchar_t *`.

Comment: You'd better say what version of the Visual C++ compiler, `initializer_list` support is brand new and probably also changing quickly.

Comment: Does the error still occur if you change `contains(val` to `contains(val.c_str()` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb In that case the error is _could not deduce template argument_

Answer (score 1):

I remember that VS has a bug where they would do double-deduction in certain scenarios, and I think that's what's happening here. Clang also compiles it both ways, so since clang + gcc agree, it's likely a VS bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which was resolved by switching to the latest VS Pro version. I think this bug was addressed in the latest VS pro version as I remember seeing it in a change-log at some point.